# Google Chrome's icons are... red?

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome

I don't really know how to explain that, but some vector graphics are... red. Namely:

- The new tab icon;
- The back button;
- The forward button;
- The refresh button;
- The extension menu button;
- The Incognito mode marker icon;
- The application menu icon.

Both Incognito and Normal modes are affected.

Does anyone have the same issue?
Does anyone have thoughts regarding the cause?

[image: [Can't post an image without 10 reputation...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qUzX6.png)]

Windows:

- **Spec:** 64bit
- **Edition:** Windows 10 Education N
- **Version:** 2004
- **Installed on:** 2020-08-13
- **OS build:** 19041.1288
- **Experience:** Windows Feature Experience Pack 120.2212.3920.0

Chrome: `Version 97.0.4688.4 (Official Build) dev (64-bit)`

Comment: When asking _« Does anyone have the same issue? »_ I want to make it clear that colors other than red are also acceptable...

Comment: I do not see red icons or tabs (other than my Account Initial which has always be red - at least in the recent past). Try uninstalling Chrome,restarting and installing Chrome fresh.

Comment: Looks like someone applied a theme...

Comment: @acejavelin Never touched the theme before. Just tried to apply a random theme from the Chrome Web Store, and the icons were still red with the theme on. Reset the theme to default: red. // Could it come from the latest Windows 10 update, [which also made the search menu dark](https://www.windowslatest.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/Windows-Search-dark-mode-1.jpg)?

Comment: Did you get Chrome from a non-Google site?  Chrome here (64-bit) is version 95 and I just checked for updates.

Comment: @John It was years ago, but I don't think I downloaded it from a non-Google site. Regarding the version: it's Chrome's Dev Channel, `97` matches what's on https://chromereleases.googleblog.com.

Comment: Most up to Chrome is Version 95.0.4638.69 (Official Build) (64-bit) . There is no V97 for Google Chrome .  So you don't  have true Google copy.

Comment: I think if you uninstall Chrome as I had suggested, restart and install from Google you will be at version 95 and the red icons may disappear.

Comment: @John Again: https://chromereleases.googleblog.com/2021/11/dev-channel-update-for-desktop.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When running an unstable browser, i suggest keeping keeping up with appropriate channels to track bugs. This is a known issue and is being fixed, see [this bug tracker](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1265339&q=red%20icon&can=2) Either run stable or live with things like this.